# Android tablet, user profiles, change owner?

Tags: settings, 4.4-kitkat, profiles

How can I change which user profile is the "owner" profile?  Possible?  Running 4.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

I read from [a forum](http://androidforums.com/nexus-7-2012/653737-change-owner-user-account.html) that for security reasons, the only way to change the owner is to do a Factory Reset.

Answer (score 1):

I just kept removing other Google accounts (all in this case) until the one I wanted was listed as owner. Not sure how the owner was changed from the initial Google account. It should selectable.